# Filtering out good traffic on Python from a dataset

Tags: python, dataset

I have an assignment as listed below for a class. I have figured out how to get the correct information from the file, but I haven't figured out how to filter out the good traffic as requested.

Using Python, print the malicious traffic as shown in item 1 and having a frequency of more than 100. Use the columns Use the columns of source, destination, protocol, length, and info to find the frequency of each result from the dataset. Filter out the good traffic that has protocols starting with alphabetic letters.

I have tried different filter items to get the good traffic (begins with things like UDP) but it is not working. This is what I have so far that gives me the right result according to the assignment.

```
import pandas as pd
data = "C:/Schoolwork/Unit10.csv"
nd = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",", decimal=".", header=0)
result = nd.groupby(["Source", "Destination", "Protocol", "Length", "Info"]).size().nlargest(1)

print(result)
```

Comment: check out [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: example of the CSV file...